# What foods are safe to leave in the car over a long period of time?

Tags: food-safety, storage

I'm going on a long distance permanent relocation road trip and have some random stuff left at home that I can either throw out or bring along.

What foods are safe to leave in the car over a long period of time?

Comment: Please clarify: will you come back or are you moving permantly? Welcome, btw!

Comment: Sorry, but there are thousands of foods in the world. It is impossible to list all the safe ones here. You can read up on basic food safety in our tag wiki, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info, or if you are not certain which foods require refrigeration, check them up on a database for shelf life such as StillTasty.

Comment: @rumtscho I understood this as a "how do I know" not a "list of things" question, where the answer is that it's the same as leaving it without refrigeration at home, except the shelf life might be a bit reduced compared to that if it's summer and your car is hot.

Comment: All right, it's still closed, but I've pointed to our canonical question about food left at room temperature. The same advice applies here: either things need refrigeration or they don't. (Again, with the caveat that you'll need to be more careful if your car gets hot in the sun.)

Comment: @Jefromi I pointed to our tag wiki because it has a very well structured text on the basics and ends with links to some very important places to read further, including the question you posted here. I think we should make more use of such a good resource, now almost nobody comes to it (it is somewhat hidden). For the actual closure, I don't care that much if it is seen as a list or a duplicate of the basics of temperature/refrigeration, it was somewhat unclear from the start.